# Make checkboxes from a int value in C# (for silverlight)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0

I want to read a parsed int value from silverlight slider to make checkboxes.

For example the slider has value 7, I`ll press a button and make 7 checkboxes.

How do I do that?

Comment: Please note the Windows Phone 7 is based on Silverlight 3 (not 4). I have updated your question (and tags) accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example. It even remembers the checked state of boxes when more are added.

Assuming this XAML:

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="7" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="1"
        x:Name="mySlider" ValueChanged="mySlider_ValueChanged" />

<StackPanel x:Name="chkContainer" />
```

This is the event handler

```
private void mySlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    if (chkContainer != null) // It could be null during page creation (add event handler after construction to avoid this)
    {
        // The following works because the both the small and large change are one
        // If they were larger you may have to add (or remove) more at a time
        if (chkContainer.Children.Count() < mySlider.Value)
        {
            chkContainer.Children.Add(new CheckBox { Content = mySlider.Value.ToString() });
        }
        else
        {
            chkContainer.Children.RemoveAt(int.Parse(mySlider.Value.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to capture their values in a viewmodel, adding the checkboxes in the code-behind may not be the best approach.

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _sliderValue;
    public int SliderValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _sliderValue;
        }
        set
        {
            _sliderValue = value;

            while ( SliderValue > CheckboxValues.Count )
            {
                CheckboxValues.Add( false );
            }

            // remove bools from the CheckboxValues while SliderValue < CheckboxValues.Count
            // ...
        }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<Boolean> _checkboxValues = new ObservableCollection<Boolean>();
    public ObservableCollection<Boolean> CheckboxValues
    {
        get
        {
            return _checkboxValues;
        }
        set
        {
            if ( _checkboxValues != value )
            {
                _checkboxValues = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged( "CheckboxValues" );
            }
        }
    }
```

then in xaml, something like:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CheckboxValues}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Boolean}">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding self}">Hello World</CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox can be instantiated and added to a default project page with the following code.

```
        var cb = new CheckBox();
        ContentPanel.Children.Add(cb);
```